# Need to create a new admin login for codeigniter through phpmyadmin

Tags: codeigniter, hash

I am fairly new to codeigniter and have recently copied over a website with admin users that I do not have the login details for. I want to create a new admin through phpMyAdmin so I can login to the backend of the website.

I have inserted a new admin with name and tried both a) typing in a password and using md5 hash from the dropdown and b) using a third party md5 hash and copying that into the field. Once saved however the admin login doesn't work.

The only other thing I can see different is the ip address field which appears to be encrypted differently as the hash is only 7 characters long, but I'm not sure if that should affect it or what the encryption method for that might be.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: md5 not suitable for login passwords any more you should use some thing like http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Which script you are using ?

Comment: does your user table has some role field?

Comment: Are you sure its md5? Can't you look at the code and see what's using, and use the same code to create a new user?

Comment: Show login controller, with login and register methods.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 yeah I have read that, it actually appears to be in sha1 but I believe that's much the same. But for now it's a bit of a practice so I'm not too fussed about that, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @PraveenKumar sorry I'm not sure I understand that, when I think of scripts I just think of javascript :S

Comment: @DMinch With which script i meant which website you copied from codecanyon or something like that

Comment: @PraveenKumar no it's a standard codeigniter install as far as I am aware. It's actually just a site on my hosting that I copied, but I didn't make this one myself

Comment: @DMinch Track your login function for admin.. there must be a line for converting your password input into database password type. there you can find encryption type of password replace database password with **your pass + that encryption method** and you can login to that system.. see if that helps you...

Comment: Issue has been resolved below but thank you all for taking the time and offering your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have website code with database in phpmyadmin then you can find the website link/url for signup by look into controllers...

Try signup with that link... put your desired password and complete signup...

After signup go in phpmyadmin and the database of the website and find user table.. find your newly inserted user row... copy password of your row and and paste in the default admin user password column data... 
you will be able to login to the website with your password...

**EDIT:**

please comment out below line like

```
/*  if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in() || !$this->ion_auth->is_admin())
            {
                redirect('auth', 'refresh');
            } */
```

and then put in url example.com/Auth/create_user
and create a user... let it create a new row in the user table and you can do 2 things...
1) Check in the database is dere any column for assign admin role... assign ur newly added user as admin role... something like **is_admin** or **role**

2) copy the newly added user password from the table password column of the user row and replace with the password of the admin user row password column in the database

Let me know if it helped...

Comment: @Ashish_Raj unfortunately the only links I can find either don't do anything or take me to some sort of login page that has no styling or anything. I have tried copying a password from another database built on the same system and then creating a new user in this current one giving it the same password. The strange thing is the unstyled login I found first told me this account was inactive so I changed active col=1 and it then accepted my login but dumped me on the homepage. Unfortunately even though that occurred the admin login still won't accept it as a login

Comment: Ashish (sorry won't let me tag you) this is my controller/auth.php file https://gist.github.com/muncher791/f66f5d5432f97b7ec701

Comment: But I also have a module called admin with a controller admin.php which is here https://gist.github.com/muncher791/5ce82d17ee5de5f287a0

Comment: Ashish, managed to create the password as suggested and that allowed me to access the admin panel from the admin account in the database, thanks.

Comment: But it still doesn't allow the new user to access the admin, and I can't see anything that would suggest an admin group specific or anything - now I can access from the admin it isn't too important I guess but any ideas why the newly created user still can't access the admin panel once created?

Comment: Ashish - I managed to sort it, it was the relationship between three tables users, groups and users_groups which I hadn't been able to suss out, this allowed me to set my new user to an admin status, thank you so much once again for your help! All the best.